# Inline Event handler messing with event handler in separate JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could something in the code of an inline event handler like  in the HTML markup affect some code or prevent it from firing code in a JavaScript file that is later called. Suppose the JavaScript file contained something like this.

```
$(a).click(function() {
//some code
 }
```

someJavaScriptCode isn't meant to be valid JavaScript syntax. It is generated by the PrimeFaces library.

My event handler in the JavaScript file works once, but any subsequent clicks after that; it doesn't fire. The code in the inline event handler still works however. I didn't make up the inline code; it was web application's UI library doing that. I'm just wondering how I can make the code above still work.

Comment: it depends on if the inline code is the problem or not. There isnt enough information available. Are you certain of where the issue is? Without seeing any actual code its hard to know.

Comment: If you have a javascript error no javascript after the error will run. So yes, if there's an error in your inline code it will prevent code in a javascript file from firing. Check your javascript console and see if any errors are showing.

Comment: that event handler wouldn't work.... because the jquery function takes a string... you need the a tag within quotes `$('a').click(function() {}`

Answer (score 1):

If your inline code has an error in it, and it is executed before the JavaScript in your javascript file, then it will halt javascript execution which would prevent your external file javascript from running.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If that's the case, I cannot assist further without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a framework that re-renders your DOM? It seams that when you click the element, it is replaced and it looses the event that is applied in your JavaScript file.

If that is the case, place your event on a parent that is not being re-rendered, and target the element this way:

```
$( parent ).on( 'click', 'a', function (e) {})
```

The second argument in the "on" method will target any selector and apply the click even, even if the content of the parent is refreshed.

Comment: That doesn't work I'm afraid. However, let me explain further perhaps why it may not work; I didn't explain what I was trying to do in the original post. In the inline event handler, it applies or adds a class name called "green". If you click it again, it changes the class name to "red". It is red at the start by the way.

However, the code above in the separate .js file tries to see if the "red" class is there, and it does something. If it sees "green", it does a certain something. It doesn't do the certain "things", because it's way too fast in checking before the class change happens.

Comment: I'm sorry, unless everything gets re-rendered there is no was applying an event on a "static" parent would not work... Are you sure you are applying it correctly? Any way you can provide more of the most? Perhaps the html that gets rendered?